# How to access "Activity.this" in Kotlin?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have this piece of Java code:

```
MaterialDialog builder = new MaterialDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
```

I want to get the MainActivity object in Kotlin. The automatic conversion breaks at `MainActivity.this`.

Comment: Maybe `this as MainActivity`?

Comment: And if this code is not inside `MainActivity`, then which instance of `MainActivity` is it connected to (and how)? Which instance do you want to access as `this`?

Comment: The working Java code references just the activity.this, so a static one? I'm not sure tho.

Comment: Is the working Java code also in a completely separate file?

Comment: How is this code called, if not in `MainActivity` but still casting `this` to `MainActivity`? In a subclass maybe?

Comment: It turns out that it **was** related to the activity, so `this@MainActivity` actually worked.

Answer (score 315, accepted):

You can get a reference to your `MainActivity` object in Kotlin by using a [qualified `this`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/this-expressions.html#qualified). e.g.:

```
class MyActivity : MainActivity() {
    val builder = MaterialDialog.Builder(this@MyActivity)
}
```

Comment: How about Fragment? I've injected Context into Fragment(with `@ActivityContext` attribute), now I need Activity. Of course, I know about `getActivity()` (Kotlin `activity`) in the Fragment, but is the second way okay or cause I have Context, it's better to use it to access to the activity?

Comment: @Dr.jacky I think you can do ' (context as? YourActivity)' cast. Now you can access your activity methods

Comment: @siddarth-g if you are having an issue with unresolved references then I recommend creating a new question with an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to get help.

Comment: @mfulton26 its not compilation issue this@ActivityName did not work for me in another project as well.

Answer (score 35):

Try this label instead

```
this@YourActivityName
```

Comment: unresolevd reference

Comment: It doesn't compile

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky  change the ActivityName to your Activity name -_-

Comment: @SiddarthG make sure your inner class is marked with "inner" this was my problem

Answer (score 13):

Answer is: **this@ActivityName**

For example: You should use it if you would like to define "Context" in MainActivity.kt

```
var mContext:Context = this@MainActivity
```

Why? Because in Kotlin language @ has mean "of" such as:

```
val a = this@A // A's this
```

If you want to learn more information, you can look Kotlin Language website:
[This Expression in Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/this-expressions.html)

Answer (score 10):

If you are calling Activity.this from an inner class, you have to put **inner** before the class

```
class MyActivity : MainActivity() {
    // Call from class itself
    val builder = MaterialDialog.Builder(this@MyActivity) 

    inner class Inner {
        this@MyActivity // Call from the inner class 
    }
}
```

Comment: @Allen you are correct, inner keyword is required to access the Activity inside inner class

Answer (score 5):

In kotlin

```
this@MainActivity
```

is equivalent to JAVA

```
MainActivity.this
```

Answer (score 1):

Just as you do in java for getting the context of activity as MainActivtiy.this , in kotlin you will get the context as **this@MainActivity**

Comment: are you adding this comments for  what? Can you give some resolved reference? It will helpful to us, So that we will follow it from next time

Answer (score 0):

`getActivity()` equivalent is `this@activity_name` 
in case of builder for materialDialog

```
materialDialog = MaterialDialog.Builder(this)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the object of activity like this.

```
class DemoActivity : BaseActivity() {
    val builder = MaterialDialog.Builder(this@DemoActivity)
}
```