# Unresolved reference: runOnUiThread Kotlin

Tags: android, multithreading, kotlin

I'm trying to make work this http call with `okhttp3`

I was following this [tutorial](https://medium.com/@rohan.s.jahagirdar/android-http-requests-in-kotlin-with-okhttp-5525f879b9e5) but I can't find out why `RunOnUiThread` isn't working. I have to say that i'm very new to kotlin.

there is my code :

```kotlin
class ImgurAPI(accessToken: String, refreshToken: String, FetchCompleteListener) {
    fun test() {
        var client = OkHttpClient()
        var request = OkHttpRequest(client)

        val url = "http://api.plos.org/search?q=title:%22Drosophila%22%20and%20body:%22RNA%22&fl=id,abstract&wt=json&indent=on"

        request.GET(url, object: Callback {
            override fun onResponse(call: Call?, response: Response) {
                val responseData = response.body()?.string()
                runOnUiThread{
                    try {
                        var json = JSONObject(responseData)
                        println("Request Successful!!")
                        println(json)
                        val responseObject = json.getJSONObject("response")
                        val docs = json.getJSONArray("docs")
                        this@MainActivity.fetchComplete()
                    } catch (e: JSONException) {
                        e.printStackTrace()
                    }
                }
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call?, e: IOException?) {
                println("Request Failure.")
            }
        })
    }

}
```

I also have an Unresolved Reference on `this@MainActivity` if you know why.

Comment: It should be `runOnUiThread` i.e. first letter on lower case. But I highly suggest to switch to coroutines, as they have better and easier mechanism to switch threads.

Comment: are you executing the code in fragment or activity ?

Comment: in a mainActivity.kt that just nstanciate the object and call the function

Comment: `this@MainActivity` means "use `this` in an outer class called MainActivity". See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41617042/how-to-access-activity-this-in-kotlin - it does not mean you can access `this` from another class.

Answer (score 0):

To access this@MainActivity, try declaring your class inside onCreate (this should also solve  your runOnUiThread issue).

Example:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
  private lateinit var imgurApi: ImgurAPI

  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    // Your code here 
  }
}
```

I'm not sure where `FetchCompleteListener` comes from or what it's for, but in the tutorial it appears to be an interface he's implementing in the activity class (`class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), FetchCompleteListener`)  whereas you're passing it as a parameter to your ImgurAPI class which is not correct.